# Rails send_file/send_data sends pdf file without content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf, ruby-on-rails-4.2, wicked-pdf, ruby-2.3

I am generating a pdf file using `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string`. File itself generates fine, when saved in disk and opened.

But when same file sent via `send_data`, browser downloads file with pages as per generated file but without any text/content in it. All pages are blank. Here is code snippet

```
send_data File.open(pdf_file.path, 'rb').read, type: 'application/pdf', filename: 'abc.pdf'
```

I have also tried `send_file` without any success.

Environment vars

```
Rails Version: 4.2.8
Ruby Version: 2.3.3
WickedPdf Ver: 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue [in the wicked_pdf_issues project](https://github.com/unixmonkey/wicked_pdf_issues/) in [this commit](https://github.com/unixmonkey/wicked_pdf_issues/commit/f9002a693b84f2ed04df1e46e5cef93d710b6621)

This code downloads and displays just fine:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf do
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<html><head><title>foo</title></head><body><h1>This is a PDF</h1></body></html>')
    Tempfile.create do |t|
      t.binmode
      t.write(pdf)
      t.rewind
      t.close
      send_data File.open(t.path, 'rb').read, type: 'application/pdf', filename: 'abc.pdf'
    end
  end
end
```

You can see the result by [going here and clicking the download PDF link](http://wicked-pdf-issues.herokuapp.com/pages/issue_45080858).